# Ping test for 4 hours

Tags: linux, shell, ping

I am trying to perform a ping a test to the servers for 4 hours
I tried using

> ping -t '14400' IP-ADDRESS

but i am getting a following error:
"ping: ttl 14400 out of range"
Is there any other way around it?

Comment: no, its on linux based system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `t` option to `ping` sets the time-to-live field in the packet, this has nothing to do with how many pings are sent or for what duration. IIRC the IPV4 TTL field typically limits the number of routers the packet may traverse (max "hops").

You should probably use `ping -c count -i interval` for example `ping -c 240 -i 60` would send one ping every 60 seconds for four hours.

This probably isn't a good use of ping. The manual says

> This program is intended for use in network testing, measurement and management.
>       Because of the load it can impose on the network it is unwise to use ping
>       during normal operations or from automated scripts.

Comment: Unless you own the server you're pinging, you probably should find another way to do whatever it is that you are trying to do.  Otherwise, you could be bringing some trouble on yourself, seriously, and I can't imagine what information this would provide to you other than that the server is still alive -- even then, a bad way to check.